# SearchView suggestions are showing over the widget

Tags: android

I'm using the searchview at the top of my activity positioned just below the action bar, the problem is that the suggestions are displayed over the searchview so the user cant see the typed the text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map.searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_map.searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_container">

    <!-- The map fragments will go here --> 
</RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: fixed by adding this view to the bottom of the relativelayout and setting it to the anchor <View 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map.dropDownAnchor"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_map.searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

Comment: If your problem has been fixed then post this as answer and you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by adding this view to the bottom of the relativelayout and setting it to the anchor

```
  <View android:id="@+id/fragment_map.dropDownAnchor"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_map.searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

no clue what the official answer even means. a work colleague aided me and I wanted to show how this can be achieved:

it can be done programatically by getting the textview as an AutoCompleteTextview:

imagine you have a searchview in xml like this:

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    app:closeIcon="@drawable/close_x_icon"
                    app:queryBackground="@drawable/search_bg_expanded"
                    app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/empty_drawable"
                    app:searchIcon="@null" />
```

then in code do this:

```
val searchText = searchView.findViewById<TextView>(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text) as? AutoCompleteTextView
        searchText?.dropDownAnchor = searchView.id
```

so once you cast it to an AutocompleteTextView you can change the anchor basically.